# Cannot start guest ubuntu 15.10 in vmware 12.10 on host windows 10 after install updates and restart

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have been using ubuntu 15.10 on vmware workstation 12.10 for days. Yesterday when I logged into it, there were updates available. I installed updates and chose "restart now". But the system failed to start. Screens are shown as [Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7uv2.png). It was Screen 1 after power on and then Screen 2 and finally Screen 3. Nothing happened nextly.

After searching, I tried to add "blacklist i2c-piix4" to the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and the line "piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled" in the first screen disappeared. But everything remained the same and the system still cannot start.

I am not good at resolving this. I have tried all I can find in google but still fail. Hope someone in the forum can give clear steps so that I can bring back my virtual machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting the Ubuntu VM, click in the VM window, so the Ubuntu VM has access to your keyboard input, then hold shift. A boot menu will popup. Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select the previous kernel version.

On Ubuntu 15.10 as of today, the previous kernel is 4.2.0-27. Select the one that doesn't show (upstart) or (recovery mode).

You can use this method until VMware or Ubuntu releases a fix.

If you want to set 4.2.0-27 as the default to load so you don't have to hold the shift key on start, then follow the instructions here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: Thanks a lot! VM gets start in this way. Seems there are some bugs leading kernel 4.2.0-30 cannot work with vmware?

Comment: Happy to help. A bug has been filed regarding kernel 4.2.0-30. Shouldnt be long until a fix is released for Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Virtual Machine Setting > Under hardware tab > select processor > tick "disable acceleration for binary translation"